# Cannot create user in MariaDB with MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a user in MariaDB 10.1 with the following statement:

```
 CREATE USER 'exporter' IDENTIFIED BY 'exporter' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3;
```

However this command fails with:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3' at line 1

It works when omitting the `WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MariaDB < 10.2 it works if I split the statements:

```sql
CREATE USER 'exporter' IDENTIFIED BY 'exporter';
GRANT [...] WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3;
```

For newer versions please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56038189/478406).

Comment: Hello Robert , sadly my node is on mariadb 10.1 and the GRANT statement still doesnt work for me !

Answer (score 1):

The syntax mentioned is available since MariaDB `10.2.0`.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-user/

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo... I edited my question.

`MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'exporter' IDENTIFIED BY 'exporter' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3' at line 1`

Comment: According to the docs this should work. Can you try `WITH `MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS` '3';` with the quotes .(SO messing the quotes). Like, there is a comment at the end of the link saying something with quotes: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-user/

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't work. It gives the same error message.

Comment: I have 10.0.38 and it doesn't work either. I looked again, we need to upgrade our software I guess :)

Comment: Maybe this only works with 10.2 and later. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-1020-release-notes/ states: "New CREATE USER options for limiting resource usage and tls/ssl" but this would look like as if the other options should be working.

Answer (score 1):

The 10.2 syntax implies that the password option comes *after* the resource options.

```
CREATE USER 'exporter'
    WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3
    IDENTIFIED BY 'exporter';
```